# How to use Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to wrap my head around when exactly I should use Fragments and if I'm going to use them how to do so properly.

To my understanding Fragments should be used if you want a more flexible UI as it will be easier when rotating the device and easier to have your layout work with multiple screen sizes.

It seems to me that it is good to use them because you could have an app with ONE activity and multiple Fragments so the activity will be able to get calls from callbacks while the Fragments change what the user is seeing and interacting with.  If I were to compare two apps, one made with Activities and the other with Fragments I would imagine to see something like this:

Activity app has a log in screen.  The user can log in and it brings them to the main menu (New Activity).  Once there they select the Friend button which brings them to a new Friend activity.

Fragment app has an Activity that loads the Log in Fragment into it's FrameLayout.  The Log in Fragment allows the user to log into their account.  Once it logged in, it replaces the Log in Fragment in the FrameLayout with the Main Menu Fragment.  User presses Friend button, it opens the new Friend Fragment in the Activities FrameLayout.  In this case all the work is being done in the Fragments but the Activity is just really holding them.

Please tell me why this is the incorrect use... or why this is correct.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, all in all I could agree with what you said.

Comment: Excellent. I just wanted to ensure that I wasn't implementing Fragments incorrectly while creating an app I'm working on. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official Fragments doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). Short answer: always use Fragments. Fragments are better for reusability, flexibility, etc., etc.

Comment: Okay great.  Essentially you just use them on top of an Activity.  But you still have multiple activities for different kinds of things.